# My F3 wont show my coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]When I press F3 in minecraft, it shows everything like normal BUT my coordinates.

I haven't messed with any settings, or done anything really at all. The other day it just stopped showing them.

Is anyone else having this problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this? It sounds odd.

Comment: ignore the chat lol

Answer (score 2):

Are any other players on the server experiencing this? If so `/gamerule reducedDebugInfo` may be set to true. This would have to be tuned on manually, for a specific reason.

If you are an administrator, just run:
`/gamerule reducedDebugInfo false`
Otherwise, kindly ask an admin why it's turned on, and see if you can resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everyone on the server is able to access their coordinates. I seem to be the only one with this problem, since I've asked around at least